# Failed to a create file through Tomcat

Tags: file, jsp, certificate

I made a certificate generation software.

However, it can't save files sucessfully.
I mean that the code in the 'RootCertGenerator.java' should generate a 'rootCertificate.cer' file. which is successfully work on pure java.

But when I run 'generateRootCert.jsp' on tomcat it it fails to generate the file

please help me

--generateRootCert.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=EUC-KR"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.DriverManager" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Connection" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.Statement" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.SQLException" %>
<%@ page import="java.sql.ResultSet" %>
<%@ page import="myPackage.Utils" %>
<%@ page import="myPackage.RootCertGenerator" %>

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=EUC-KR">
<title>Make root Certificate</title>
</head>
<% 
RootCertGenerator.execute();
%>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

--RootCertGenerator.java

```
package myPackage;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal;

import org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMWriter;
import org.bouncycastle.x509.X509V1CertificateGenerator;
//add 20130424
//import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

//add 20130427
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.ResultSet;


/**
 * Basic X.509 V1 Certificate creation.
 */
public class RootCertGenerator
{


    public static X509Certificate generateV1Certificate(KeyPair pair)
        throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchProviderException, SignatureException
    {
        //add 20130424
        //Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
        // generate the certificate
        X509V1CertificateGenerator  certGen = new X509V1CertificateGenerator();

        certGen.setSerialNumber(BigInteger.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        certGen.setIssuerDN(new X500Principal("CN=Test Certificate"));
        certGen.setNotBefore(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000))); //1 week
        certGen.setNotAfter(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)));
        certGen.setSubjectDN(new X500Principal("CN=Test Certificate"));
        certGen.setPublicKey(pair.getPublic());
        certGen.setSignatureAlgorithm("SHA256WithRSAEncryption");

        //return certGen.generateX509Certificate(pair.getPrivate(), "BC");
        return certGen.generateX509Certificate(pair.getPrivate());
    }

    //////////added by jeon
    public static void pemEncodeToFile(String filename, Object obj, char[] password) throws Exception{
    PEMWriter pw = new PEMWriter(new FileWriter(filename));
       if (password != null && password.length > 0) {
           pw.writeObject(obj, "DESEDE", password, new SecureRandom());
       } else {
           pw.writeObject(obj);
       }
       pw.flush();
       pw.close();
    }
    //////////add 20130427
    public static String pemEncodeToString(Object obj, char[] password) throws Exception{
        PEMWriter pw = new PEMWriter(new StringWriter(1));
           if (password != null && password.length > 0) {
               pw.writeObject(obj, "DESEDE", password, new SecureRandom());
           } else {
               pw.writeObject(obj);
           }
           String str=null;
           pw.write(str);

           return str;
           //pw.flush();
           //pw.close();
        }
    //////////add 20130427
    public static void rootCertUpdate(String rootCert)
    {
        String sql = "update testca.testca_init set certificate = '"+rootCert+"' where user_id='root'";
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Connection conn = null;
        //PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

        Statement stmt = null;
        //ResultSet rs = null;

        String jdbcDriver = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
        String dbUser = "root";
        String dbPass = "forgetmenot";

        try{
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcDriver, dbUser, dbPass);
            stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

        }catch(Exception ex){System.out.println("Error 2: " +ex);}
    }
    //////////added by jeon

    public static void execute()
        throws Exception
    {
        Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());
        // create the keys
        KeyPair          pair = Utils.generateRSAKeyPair();


        ////private key
        PrivateKey      key = (PrivateKey)pair.getPrivate();
        // generate the certificate
        X509Certificate cert = generateV1Certificate(pair);
        byte[] a = cert.getEncoded();
        //System.out.println(a);
        //System.out.println(cert);

        ////////////////////writing root certificate
        PEMWriter pemWrt = new PEMWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));

        pemWrt.writeObject(cert);

        pemEncodeToFile("rootCertificate.cer", cert, null);

        //20130428
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos);
        PrintStream old = System.out;
        System.setOut(ps);
        System.out.println(cert);
        //System.out.flush();
        pemWrt.flush();
        System.setOut(old);
        System.out.println("Here: " + baos.toString());
        pemWrt.close();

        rootCertUpdate(baos.toString());

        // show some basic validation
        cert.checkValidity(new Date());

        cert.verify(cert.getPublicKey());

        System.out.println("valid certificate generated");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not only provide the filename of the certificate (rootCertificate.cer), but also the full path where it should be created if you use this class within Tomcat.

You can edit the following line. Instead

```
pemEncodeToFile("rootCertificate.cer", cert, null);
```

write something like

```
pemEncodeToFile("C:/servers/rootCertificate.cer", cert, null);
```

or

```
pemEncodeToFile("C:\\servers\\rootCertificate.cer", cert, null);
```

The file should be created in the mentioned path. Make sure that the folder (in this example "servers") already exists. You could also enhance your method signature by the filename and edit the filename in the JSP.

Comment: could you give me an example for 'PEMWriter pw = new PEMWriter(new FileWriter(filename));' on windows systems?